# Executing a function for each element in an array using promise

Tags: node.js, promise

I need to execute a function for each item in an array using promise. I hope promise.all is suitable for this. But, the rest of the function executions should continue to execute when (function execution of) any of the item in array is terminated with error. Does promise.all behave this way?

Example: In the following code-snippet, the function getInfo needs to be executed for each of the item `parallely` and also when the result of getInfo(item1) should be returned when it is available without waiting for the result to be available for item2 & item3. And also, **error happened for any of the item should not affect the execution of rest of the items** in the array

```
var arrayIterate = [item1, item2, item3]

function getInfo(item){
  // do stuff
};
```

Comment: `Promise.all` does not execute functions. It waits for multiple promises.

Answer (score 1):

Not promise.all behaves in this manner. But you can chain the functions manually over their callbacks.

**Just like this** :

`for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){ 
   myFunction('param1', function(){ 
   });
}`

`myFunction(param1, callback){  if(error){ callback() }else{ 
   //do something and then callback()
 } 
}`

Like this even if your code gets error it won't stop at that point but will execute for all element in array.

PS: But Remember `for loop` should not be used here as it won't wait for callbacks. So, use **Recursive Techniques** to perform function execution over every element of array.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all()` is perfect for this.

Let's say you have a list of URLs and you want to fetch the data from those URLs.

```
var request = require('request-promise') // The simplified HTTP request client 'request' with Promise support. Powered by Bluebird.

var Promise = require('bluebird');

var urls = ["a-url", "some-other-url"];

var promises = [];

// You create the promise for each url and push them in an array

urls.forEach(function(url){
    promises.push(request.get(url));
});

// After that you can call the Promise.all() on this promises array and get the results.

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    // results is an array of results from all the urls

    // No error encountered

    // Celebrate victory

}).catch(function(err) {
    // Even if one error occurs, it will come here and won't execute any further.
    // Handle error 

});
```

You can even go for `Promise.map()`

Go ahead and read the Bluebird docs:  http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html